# Symfony5 - recovering only a few fields from an entity

Tags: api, symfony, serialization, api-platform.com

I want to create a route that will return a list of one of my entities, with only some of the fields of it.

I think it can be achieved with serialization groups but maybe it's not the easiest way to do it.

So I've thought to simply add a new custom route, called `special_get` to test with the `normalization_group` `user:special` as follow :

```
/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     attributes={
 *          "normalization_context"={"groups"={"user:read", "user:list", "user:special"}},
 *          "denormalization_context"={"groups"={"user:write"}},
 *          "order"={"availabilities.start": "ASC"}
 *     },
 *     collectionOperations={
 *          "get"={
 *              "mehtod"="GET",
 *              "security"="is_granted('ROLE_USER')",
 *              "normalization_context"={"groups"={"user:list"}},
 *          },
 *        "special_get"={
 *             "method"="GET",
 *             "path"="/user/specialroute",
 *             "normalization_context"={"groups"={"user:special"}}
 *        },
 *     }
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UserRepository::class)
 */
```

And apply this `group` only to the few fields I want to return :

```
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     * @Groups({"user:read", "user:list", "user:write", "user:special"})
     */
    private $firstName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     * @Groups({"user:write", "user:read", "user:list",  "user:special"})
     */
    private $photo;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Availability::class, mappedBy="entityname", cascade={"remove"})
     * @Groups({"user:read", "user:list", "user:write"})
     * @ApiSubresource()
     */
    private $availabilities;
```

That does create me a new route on the swagger interface as I want, but I get a `500` that says :

```
An error occured
Cannot select distinct identifiers from query with LIMIT and ORDER BY on a column from a fetch joined to-many association. Use output walkers.*
```

Does anyone have an idea on where this error might come from ?

Or if there is a better way to achieve recovering only a few fields form an entity on a special route ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, regarding to the error message your problem is in `order` attribute that orders results by `availabilities.start` property that not added to your normalization group.

So you have to ways here:

- add `availabilities` property to the normalization group
- remove this attribute

As far as I know, api-platform didn't supports ordering attribute per operation at this moment, [seems it shouldn't](https://github.com/api-platform/core/issues/2690#issuecomment-480274648).

Comment: Taht's my bad I have this field in the entity but didn't thought it was relevant (forgetting about the annotation above) I updated the issue.

Comment: You didn't understand me) You need to add `"user:special"` group in list of groups of this property) Or remove `"order"={"availabilities.start": "ASC"}`. At this moment api-platform tries to order results by `availabilities.start` but it haven't access to it since it doesn't present in this normalization group.

Comment: Alright then if I don't want to show this field I should rather opt for dynamic serialization groups

Comment: Or you can add here this group for this property, and then in decorated normalizer delete it from result, in example. It is the easiest way, imho.

Comment: Yes I see what you mean. I still have a few errors but not related to this issue, so once again thank you for saving the day !

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PropertyFilter](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/filters/#property-filter) so you can select specific fields

Enable the filter:

```
* @ApiFilter(PropertyFilter::class)
```

Import the class `use ApiPlatform\Core\Serializer\Filter\PropertyFilter;`

Now you can filter the serialization properties with the following query:

```
?properties[]=title&properties[]=shortDescription
```

*You can add as many properties as you need.*